# Azure kubernetes - Azure CNI & Istio, sidecar IP allocation?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, sidecar, istio-kiali

Our Azure kubernetes cluster is configured with Azure CNI for networking which uses the subnet with CIDR: /21.

As we are planning to deploy Istio service mesh and additional sidecars for log shipping, how would those impact the available IPs? Would those consume the IPs? If so, how to avoid the IP congestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kubernetes allocates a single IP per pod, so no matter how many sidecars you have, a single pod will only have a single IP. Basically, you dont need to do anything in this regard